# VBA handling IF/THEN statements in loop for large datasets (on multiple sheets)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm very new to VBA, and am learning to process a large (10+year) dataset to convert into suitable format for analyses. The dataset is on 52 different sheets, with the same layout format (but different range - representing different numbers of observations) on each sheet.

This data relates to sightings of elephants. Currently, I have all the elephant ID codes in column A, and subsequent columns are observations on different dates, with a 1 to indicate presence of an individual.

I need to replace all these 1s with the ID code for the individual (i.e. the corresponding row text from column A). I have set up an input for the user defined range, which gets around the problem of different range sizes for different sheets. The point I'm stuck with is figuring out which argument applies to the ????? in my code below: What argument returns the text from the first column that row?

[I had originally recorded a macro with an if, then = A2, then dragged and filled to the whole range. But of course this doesn't work on the other sheets].

What I have so far is;

```
Sub ReplaceOneswithIDcode()
'
' replace all ones with ID code.
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address,  Type:=8)
For Each rng In InputRng
If rng.Value = 1 Then
     ?????
End If

End Sub
```

Of course, any other logical approach that could work would be welcome too.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance - been off sick but keen to get into this again. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fill `Array("Elephants", "Elephants (2)")` in with the names of the worksheets that you want to process.

```
Sub FillElephantIDs()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim lastColumn As Integer, lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim ws

    For Each ws In Array("Elephants", "Elephants (2)")
        With Worksheets(ws)
            lastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

            For x = 2 To lastRow

                .Range(.Cells(x, 2), .Cells(x, lastColumn)).Replace 1, .Cells(x, 1).Value

            Next

        End With

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the ID code using the row number of the cell you are looking at and the column number from column A - so the missing code ????? is

```
rng.Value = Cells(rng.Row, 1).Value
```

where `rng.Row` is the row index of the cell (rng) you are looking at and "1" is Column A.

You also need a `'Next rng'` after `'End If'`

Alternatively, you can set the InputRng to be the used range on the sheet, which will just perform the action on all the used cells on the sheet - see second code sample (saves you having to select the range).

Hope this works for you (this my first 'answer' ever - I thought it was time I started to give back - so feel free to spot problems or errors). Cheers, Claire

```
Sub ReplaceOneswithIDcode()
'
' replace all ones with ID code.
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range

On Error GoTo Handler:
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
For Each rng In InputRng
If rng.Value = 1 Then
     rng.Value = Cells(rng.Row, 1).Value
End If
Next rng
Handler:
End Sub

Sub ReplaceOneswithIDcode_usedrange()
'
' replace all ones with ID code in used range.
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range

On Error GoTo Handler:
Set InputRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each rng In InputRng
If rng.Value = 1 Then
     rng.Value = Cells(rng.Row, 1).Value
End If
Next rng
Handler:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without iteration like follows

```
Sub ReplaceOneswithIDcode(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("B").Resize(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1))
            .Replace what:=1, replacement:="=OFFSET($A$1,ROW()-1,0)", lookat:=xlWhole
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

which you could use as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets '<--| loop through all worksheets of the workbook the macro resides in
        ReplaceOneswithIDcode ws
    Next ws
End Sub
```

or in any other way you need to loop a worksheet collection

Comment: @VFishlock: did you get through it?